# Not sure which Google Wallet API to use

Tags: android-pay

I'm building an application for a new small business.  They run events at race tracks, and the application is a registration system for said events.  As a small business the owner doesn't want to worry about handling people's credit card info. They are just starting up and we are building from the ground up. So we are looking at using third party services like Google Wallet and PayPal.

So looking at the documentation, we have the Instant Buy API.  Seeing as we aren't planning on taking direct credit card payments, it seems like a pain to setup payment processing through another service to use the Instant Buy. But we aren't selling a "Digital Good", as far as I can tell (I haven't seen a documented definition for this), so does that mean we can't use the API for Digital Goods?  I haven't found any documentation that lays this out as a policy. It seems like it would be a lot simpler to implement, even with the cut Google takes.

Comment: A [digital good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_goods) is something that is not shipped, but downloaded. It is not tangible. Your tickets are not digital goods.

Comment: We are not shipping a physical ticket.  The wiki article mentions electronic tickets, does that make us an electronic good?

Comment: If you're looking for **official** policy related questions, it's best to get them from [Google Support directly](https://support.google.com/wallet/business/?hl=en#topic=4490615). The operational difference between the 2 can be summarized into whether or not the business has existing PCI compliant infrastructure. Instant Buy requires it. Hth.

Answer (score 0):

There is a page at the google wallet documentation site called [Which API Should I Use?](https://developers.google.com/wallet/which-api), the first item there is:

> The quick answer: it depends on your goals, your platform and what
>   kind of goods or services you're selling. The Instant Buy APIs are for
>   selling physical goods, while digital goods sellers should use the
>   Google Wallet for Digital Goods API for web apps or Google Play In-app
>   Billing for Android for native Android apps. To engage your customers
>   with offers and loyalty programs, use the Wallet Objects API.

Now, the Instant Buy APIs are for those business that have an existing payment gateway setup, but need to offer Google Wallet as a payment option.

In your situation, as you don't have a payment processor setup:

> To sell physical goods on web apps and mobile apps that run on
>   browsers, use Instant Buy for web. You'll keep your existing payment
>   processor and optimize your payment flow with Google Wallet, just like
>   with Android. You can use Instant Buy for web to sell digital goods,
>   **but if you lack a payment processor or resources to maintain and
>   develop a PCI-compliant online store, you should use the Google Wallet
>   for Digital Goods API.**

Comment: Again, the sentence in bold only seems to be related to digital goods.  I could argue semantics about whether we are a digital good or not, but my main concern is whether there is actually some policy about physical vs digital goods, or whether this is just Google's recommendations based on the capabilities of the APIs.